# Is it possible to change the font family of a Literal in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Lets suppose I have a literal set to give the user an error message if he does not complete a asp.net textboxes with the information required. 
I know it is possible to change the color of the literal including a surrounding `<span>` tag with style inside.

Is it possible to do the same but this time to the Literal's font family?

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you change the surrounding tag's style like so? font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to a `Label`, that has various `Font` properties.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Font test" Font-Names="Comic Sans MS" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:Label>
```

Keep in mind that a `Label` adds it's own surrounding `<span>` element.

Comment: Would I still be able to use the label as a literal in terms of getting it to show a message if the user hasn't completed the required fields? Because I have a separate .cs file where I have an if else function setting Literal.Text to show an error message retrieved from ASP.Identity.

Comment: Yes, it works the same. But you need to change the .cs file to Label1.Text also.